# Printing contents in tableView

Tags: qt, qt5

I used the code in the below link 
http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-64182.html

But when I call the function using a QPushButton, the application freezes and get closed. 
What's wrong with the code?

I'm new in using print in Qt.

Comment: If you are using qtcreator, you can run on debug mode. And post here what error you got